# Blank space on right of ie mobile / Windows phone

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mobile, responsive-design

I am creating this single page as a responsive design test and it looks fine in most browsers and mobile devices (that I've checked so far), except for IE / Windows Phone. I'm using IE 11's Emulation toolbar to simulate a windows phone and there is a horizontal scroll bar that scrolls to a strange blank space appearing on the right side.

I've searched the page for any excess margin or padding but can't find any. I've also tried adding

```
html, body { 
  overflow-x:hidden; 
}
```

But that doesn't appear to work either. Which is really odd. However it DOES get rid of the space if I add

```
html, body { 
  overflow-y:hidden; 
}
```

But that also collapses the entire page along with the space. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

http://www.web-dex.com/testing/new.html

I should also add that it appears fine in Portrait view, but in landscape it has the scroll bar and blank space.

Comment: I believe Windows products reserve the space for a scroll bar even if one isn't needed or displayed.

Comment: Do they really? I guess there isn't much I can do about it if so.

Comment: I'm using a Windows Phone, it looks fine, no blank space on the right at all.

Comment: Really? that's odd. Are you using IE?

Comment: Try adding width:100%; to the html, body css. Maybe IE needs to be forced. Also, for testing purposes, add this: border-style:solid;border-width:3px; This will allow you to visually see where  the browser is calling the edge of the page or div. then set width to 0px when done.

Comment: I added with 100% to both but still nothing. I've also set a border to the html and body but I can't see anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1):

first, the 'windows phone' emulation in desktop IE 11 (v1) is not an emulator for the actual windows phone browser.

vbn is right the site looks fine on Windows Phone. My guess is your development machine does not support touch and therefor has the normal 'mouse' scrollbar which is wide, not thin like the touch scrollbar.

As someone that specializes in responsive SPA applications you are better served resizing the browser down and not trying to use any of the F12 'emulation' modes for devices. None of them are very accurate. You can just about 100% see if your RWD works by resizing the browser.

You should always test on devices, I know that is not always an option for everyone. It is a must in my experience. You don't need 100s of devices. I have 5 core devices I use, iPhone, iPad, small & large Android, Windows Phone and Surface. Touch is essential BTW, browsers on these devices operate differently, like the scroll bar.

If you cant test on real devices look at something like BrowserStack. You cant get a real sense of touch response, but you can see if things layout correctly or you code has exceptions. Visit http://modern.ie for a free 3 month subscription to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your entire page in a div and centering it:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

your entire page

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
width:95%;
}
```

Set width to whatever you want.

Comment: I just tried this and it does add a even amount of space on the left side of the page. Not exactly what I was looking for but it did help a bit.